# Interaction on namespaced SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, namespaces, visio

I am trying to insert a SVG diagram on a Web page and add JavaScript interaction.

My issue: the SVG includes elements with namespaces, and when I insert it inline, only the non-namespaced elements are rendered. I have tried direct insertion in the html, innerHTML, and the [SVGjs library](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/), all give the same result.

Is there a way to render namespaced SVG on the page and interact with it?

For the record, the SVG files come from Visio and I don't have control on the namespaces. Also, I am using Reactjs if that can help.

Sample script (both methods work but strip out namespaced elements):

```
fetch (fileURL)
.then(response => response.text())
.then((image) => {
  let startOfSvg = image.indexOf('<svg')
  startOfSvg = startOfSvg >= 0 ? startOfSvg : 0

  // innerHTML method
  document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = image.slice(startOfSvg);

  // svg.js library
  const draw = SVG(image.slice(startOfSvg))
    .addTo('#map')
    .size('100%', 450);
}
```

Comment: I have added a code sample.

Comment: if you have valid XML then [DOMParser.parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) with an SVG mime type is probably a better bet here.

Comment: Are you talking about the _Visio_ namespaces or about SVG namespace? `v:` and the like will remain invisible.

Comment: There is a checkbox to export SVG without visio namespace. Other than that, you could take a look at my exporter (it can export pure svg as well, dependong on the template you use): https://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `v:` were Visio namespaces and could be discarded. I'll try that.

Comment: @Nikolay unticking the checkbox did the trick! I was expecting a more general method to deal with namespaces, but that's great for my use case. Make it an answer?

Comment: @Christophe copied as anwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a checkbox to export SVG without visio namespace. Other than that, you could take a look at my exporter (it can export pure svg as well, depending on the template you use): https://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish